# How to know on which flutter version a perticular project is made?

Tags: flutter

i have a flutter project and when i run it, it says to migrate to current version of flutter, but i don't want to migrate it, i can change my flutter version on which this project was made, so i can run it, i have tried to change my flutter version to 1.177, 1.22, 2.2 but it is still showing migrate error, so how to know if there any file available in project folder where we can see on which flutter version this perticular project is made, or is there other way to know it? please help.

If there is anything else you need, please tell me i will provide,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `pubspec.lock` file, you can check the version of every package including flutter in it.
also, It's optional to mention the flutter version in `pubspec.yaml`.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the flutter and dart versions used in the project at the pubspec.lock file, at the very bottom.

Should be something like this:

```
sdks:
dart: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"
flutter: ">=3.0.0"
```